# "cannot read property "id" of null node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

i am trying to convert my old discord bot from node js 6.x.x to 8.x.x, i am also putting the commands in a separate folder to make it look cleaner, the command works on my old bot but not with this bot, i get

> UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of null

UPDATED CODE STILL RETURNS THE SAME:

```
var settings = '../settingsConfig/settings.json';
var file = require(settings)
const SteamTotp = require('steam-totp');
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const configS = require('../settingsConfig/ConfigSammy.json');
const configJ = require('../settingsConfig/ConfigJack.json');
const configB = require('../settingsConfig/ConfigBen.json');

module.exports.run = async (bot, message, args) => {
function myFunc(){
    var JackCode = SteamTotp.getAuthCode(configJ.sharedSecret);
    var BenCode = SteamTotp.getAuthCode(configB.sharedSecret);
    var SammyCode = SteamTotp.getAuthCode(configS.sharedSecret);

    var codess = new Discord.RichEmbed()
        .addField("__**Bens Code:**__", BenCode)
        .addField("__**Jacks Code:**__", JackCode)
        .addField("__**Sammys Code:**__", SammyCode)
        .setColor(0x00FF00)
        message.author.send(codess)
}
new myFunc();
};

module.exports.help = {
    name: "codes"
}
```

Comment: This just shows that you have no idea about the things or techniques you use. You make a new anonymous function in your `run` function and then use it as **function constructor**. As well using `async` without ever thinking about the possible consequences, just leads to errors, which you have proven to have and also proven to not know anything about JS. The provided rejection reason **can not** come from the provided code, as there is **no** `.id` being used in there.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the error comes from having `message.guild` not being defined, there for calling `message.guild.id` yields the error

The reason you're getting this specific error is since you are using the `async` keyword, which basically means you are using a promise, but you don't provide a reject method for it, hence `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning`

Comment: so i should probably define message.guild

Comment: No you should filter out direct messages.

Answer (score 0):

The error may occur because your MongoDB would not be connected. Try to repair it while installing MongoDB.